# Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "hours", intValue: nil)

Tags: json, swift, codable

I am getting a weird error and I don't understand why. This hasn't happened prior to adding the new item.

This is the error that I am getting:

> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error:
> Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "hours",
> intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [],
> debugDescription: "No value associated with key
> CodingKeys(stringValue: "hours", intValue: nil) ("hours").",
> underlyingError: nil))

---

Here is what I have setup:

**Place.Swift**:

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct Place: Codable, Identifiable {
    
    // MARK: - DEFINE PROPERTIES
    let id: Int
    var b4aId = ""
    var admission: String
    var website: String
    var hours: String
    var show = false
    
    // MARK: - SET DEFAULT PROPERTIES
    static var `default` : Place {
        Place(
            id: 0,
            admission: "Free",
            website: "Website",
            hours: "Hours"
        )
    }
    
    init(
        id: Int,
        admission: String,
        website: String,
        hours: String,
        show: Bool = false
    ) {
        self.id = id
        self.admission = admission
        self.website = website
        self.hours = hours
        self.show = show
    }
    
    init(with p: MGLocation) {
        self.id = atomicId.wrappingIncrementThenLoad(ordering: .relaxed)
        self.b4aId = p.objectId ?? ""
        self.admission = p.admission ?? ""
        self.website = p.website ?? ""
        self.hours = p.hours ?? ""
        self.show = false
    }
}
```

MGLocation.swift:

```
import Foundation
import ParseSwift

// MARK: - SET MGLOCATION PARSE OBJECT
struct MGLocation: ParseObject {
    
    // Parse Properties
    var objectId: String?
    var createdAt: Date?
    var updatedAt: Date?
    var originalData: Data?
    var ACL: ParseACL?
    
    // Custom Properties
    var admission: String?
    var website: String?
    var hours: String?
    
    // Initialization
    init() {}
    init(objectId: String?) {
        self.objectId = objectId
    }
}
```

Notes:

`admission` and `website` works just fine, but as soon as I add `hours` it crashes the app.

The database has the correct column, so I don't know what I am doing wrong compared to the others.

Also, is there an easier way to write the `Place` class without defining so many instances of keys?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that there is no `hours` in at least one entity you are trying to decode. In order to solve this make your `hours` property optional.

```
struct Place: Codable, Identifiable {
    
    // MARK: - DEFINE PROPERTIES
    let id: Int
    var b4aId = ""
    var admission: String
    var website: String
    var hours: String? // change this to an optional
    var show = false
    
    // MARK: - SET DEFAULT PROPERTIES
    static var `default` : Place {
        Place(
            id: 0,
            admission: "Free",
            website: "Website",
            hours: "Hours"
        )
    }
    
    init(
        id: Int,
        admission: String,
        website: String,
        hours: String,
        show: Bool = false
    ) {
        self.id = id
        self.admission = admission
        self.website = website
        self.hours = hours
        self.show = show
    }
    
    init(with p: MGLocation) {
        self.id = atomicId.wrappingIncrementThenLoad(ordering: .relaxed)
        self.b4aId = p.objectId ?? ""
        self.admission = p.admission ?? ""
        self.website = p.website ?? ""
        self.hours = p.hours ?? ""
        self.show = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks burnsi, that worked perfectly, can't believe I missed that - Is there a way to can clean up this Place class and not keep repeating the keys?

Comment: @SLE glad I could help. Please elaborate a bit more what you mean by `not keep repeating the keys`?

Comment: I just keep repeating, `var admission: String`, `admission: "Free",`, `admission: String,`, `self.admission = admission`, `self.admission = p.admission ?? ""` - Just wondering if there is a cleaner way to refactor my code so I'm not repeating the same key so many times.

Comment: @SLE nothing you can do about that. If you want to assign a value to a varriable you have to explicitly write it out.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the heads up - I am still learning Swift so was just curious if there was a cleared way, but thanks for the insight.